# I'm fire; I compress—what on earth am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, lateral-thinking, rhyme

I am an intricate fire,
requited or unattainable.

I rush to break
I compress
Put initiality in front of
what comes after individuality.

I am fleeting
but intense.

I am a vigorous force
upon the heart of any;
I leave a great impact.

You are bound to have encountered me
more than once in life
in more than one form.

I am not anything hot
I am not really fire,
I am not a gas either.
yet I am fire and I do compress.

What on earth am I?

---

I'm only 13, and I never really tried making a puzzle. This site inspired me to try and form a unique puzzle. I don't know much about puzzles and riddles, and I know that it's a very unkempt attempt. Do correct me, instead of opposing me for my mistakes.

### EDIT

The answer to this riddle is a single *five-letter* English word. The word has several meanings. Only two broad meanings have been explored in this rhyme.

Hints: *puberty*, *compress*.

I've narrowed down the problem for you.

Finally, watch out for any red herrings!

### EDIT$^2$

I would approve an answer which...

1. is correct
2. can demystify all the clues
3. provide an in-depth, reasonable interpretation of each line

In short, what I want is a solid comprehensive solution.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I hope you have already taken a [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). Please read the [wiki](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptic-clues/info) for cryptic clues tag and then decide if it is the right tag here.

Comment: Yes, it is. Well, at least I think so.

Comment: I have edited the tags to include riddle(because clearly, this is a riddle) and removed the cryptic clues tag because these are not cryptic clues. These are indirect references to a certain thing but not cryptic clues..

Comment: Have some patience before giving hints. Leave your riddle up for a few days before giving any.

Comment: This question was already answered, but I was thinking combustion, or internal combustion engine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be

> Crush

Meaning 1:

> Noun, infatuation

Meaning 2:

> Verb, smash

Explanation:

I am an intricate fire,
requited or unattainable.

> Clearly meaning 1 I would say. Either the crush is answered (requited) or it isn't (unattainable).

I rush to break

> Might be both meanings. A crush can break a heart, but crushing something will typically break it.

I compress

> Clearly meaning 2, compress is a synonym of crush

Put initiality in front of
what comes after individuality.

> Initiality refers to the first letter of the word, C. After individuality (I) comes the word "rush" in the previous line, together they again from the word crush.

I am fleeting
but intense.

> Meaning 1 again. Having a crush is typically very intense, but passes quite quickly. This could refer to meaning 2 as well as crushing something is intense in that sense as well.

I am a vigorous force upon the heart of any;

> This could refer to the force upon the heart of an object, but also to the force upon the heart of a person.

I leave a great impact.

> In all forms, a crush leaves a great impact.

You are bound to have encountered me
more than once in life
in more than one form.

> Refers to the several meanings of the word; everyone is bound to have encountered them at some point in their life.

Comment: Ah, that's it! It's just what I was looking for. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Can you figure out what this means?
Put initiality in front of what comes after individuality.

Comment: Haha, this reminds of that Statler & Waldorf scene... :P I'll see if I can make something of the other lines

Comment: A very good update... I'm really pleased.

Comment: Crushed heart can be similar to broken heart.

Comment: @Levieux C is the initial letter of the word 'compress', not the answer itself. See my own answer to this question. Fix the logical error.

Answer (score 9):

I have a feeling that it's

> gas

Explanation

> Thinking of an appropriate explanation for all of the clues

**EDIT**

It's obviously

> crush

But, I refuse to give up without a fight.

So here it goes:

I am an intricate fire,

> Well, fire is technically a gas.

requited or unattainable.

> Gas is unattainable. In the sense it implies freedom to soar and expand. It cannot be captured. In a poetic sense of course.

I rush to break

> Gas will rush to lose its figure or shape once released, hence implying it 'breaks'.

I compress

> Gas can be compressed.

Put initiality in front of
what comes after individuality.

> This is tough..... I don't even understand what the OP is trying to say here. This line makes no sense to me. Could you please confirm this line's meaning Soha?

I am fleeting
but intense.

> Farts.

I am a vigorous force
upon the heart of any;
I leave a great impact.

> Again, farts!

You are bound to have encountered me
more than once in life
in more than one form.

> Smelly farts. Silent farts. Wet farts. Loud farts.

There. Beat that! :D :P

**EDIT 2**

Reading Soha's comment on Levieux's answer, two can play at your game madam.

Put initiality in front of
what comes after individuality.

> In the periodic table, Xenon, a gas, comes after I (Iodine). HAH!

Comment: Lol, all I thought of was natural gas (if you get what I mean) when I first saw your answer. I couldn't stop laughing for possibly about a minute.

Comment: I am fleeting

but intense.

I am a vigorous force

upon the heart of any;     Welllllllllllll.......... :P

Comment: Well, it is not a bad fit, but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I've edited the question. Don't delete this answer, however. This could make for a refreshing, healthy dose of entertainment. :-P

Comment: There, all lines are explained :P

Comment: The second edit, I've to admit, _almost_ made me stagger. You really have a knack at solving riddles.

Comment: Thank you  :). The guys here are a huge inspiration! I learn loads everytime I open this website.

Comment: There's one fault with your second edit: Xenon ends the 5th period/row. It's the last element in the 5th horizontal block. By no means does it convey the so-called 'initiality'. :-P Otherwise, I would _stagger_.

Comment: Well, since it's the next, ie, initially in front of, Iodine, I don't see why it being the last element of any row affect the logic. Secondly, I would discourage you from answering your own question, especially when an appropriate answer has been given, and has been approved by you. Also, asking for upvotes is something else I would ask to to refrain from doing. You're spamming your own good question by needlessly answering with an explanation which is already well established in Levieux's answer. Anyway, it's your first puzzle, so no worries. Cheers and have a good time here.

Comment: Thanks, and I posted that before Leviex edited his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> a music *album*

I am an intricate fire,

> An album can be called "fire" if it's particularly good.

requited or unattainable.

> Not everyone can afford to buy an album.

I rush to break

> An artist wants to break their next album ASAP

I compress

> You compress music into different formats: .mp3, .wav, etc.

Put initiality in front of
what comes after individuality.

> I'm not sure about this part.

I am fleeting

> An album usually lasts at most 2 hours, a very fleeting amount of time.

but intense.
I am a vigorous force
upon the heart of any;
I leave a great impact.

> A great album can elicit many strong emotions within a person, and greatly influence what someone believes.

You are bound to have encountered me
more than once in life
in more than one form.

> New albums are released all the time. Most people listen to a large amount in their lives. There are many ways to listen. CD, record, concert, etc.

Comment: +1 for such an interesting answer. It's a really good fit in most places, but this is not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

### The Answer

@Leveuix is correct. The answer is

> Crush

### In-depth Analysis of Selected Lines

*1.*   I **rush** to break
*2.*   I **c**ompress
*3.*   **Put initiality in front of what comes after individuality.**

To interpret the last line, you will have to carefully observe the lines #1 and #2. It's essentially wordplay:

> Initial letter of ***c**ompress* $+$ ***rush*** after 'I' (which
>  symbolises individuality) $=$ **crush**

---

I am a vigorous force upon the heart of any;

> A `crush` can be described as a force upon a person's heart or an
>  object's (to break/compress it).
>  
>  (Referring to infatuation) A force upon a person's heart can crush it,
>  as @Techidiot pointed out in a comment. 
>  
>  You may be let down/disheartened/depressed (heart may be
>  compressed). One of the many google definitions of `crush`: *bring*
>  *about a feeling of overwhelming disappointment or embarrassment in*
>  *(someone)*. 
>  
>  A strong force upon a object's heart can smash it, as well.

---

I am fleeting but intense.

> Infatuations are typically short-lived, but intense. Similarly, it
>  takes  little time to crush anything; the effect is strong,
>  nonetheless.

---

I leave a great impact.

> In all its forms, a `crush` leaves a great impact.

---

You are bound to have encountered me more than once in life in more than one form.

> It tries to imply that that the word `crush` has multiple meanings.
>  And, everyone is guaranteed to have encountered them at some point
>  or another. All of them are so commonplace.

Comment: Okay, this is a personal opinion and not a site-policy. Self-Answers should not really be given in puzzles unless they aren't solved for months. Here, your puzzle was solved in less than 2 hours and the solver has already explained the lines of the puzzle. I don't see the reason for posting another answer explaining the same lines. Take Care in the future and happy Puzzling!!

Comment: Thanks, and I posted that before Leviex edited his answer. So, it wasn't intentional.

Answer (score -1):

> Volcano lava

That's the force we are referring to here.

Comment: +1 Good try. But, this is not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is

> love

Because

> Love is fleeting and intense.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Can you explain how your answer fits the other lines of the puzzle?